# What are the Main LaTeX Commands?

Tags: macros, texmaker, preamble

On Texmaker editor in order to overwrite existing default font type to modify it to my custom font I use the commands below, which work fine:

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
```

As far as I know, though correct me if I am wrong, that `\renewcommand`, `\usepackage`, `\documentclass`, etc. are some of the main commands for LaTeX. What about the others, `\familydefault` and `\sfdefault`? What exactly do these correspond to? Is there a full list of main LaTeX commands; or does it vary from compiler to compiler?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! No, it does not vary. `\family default`  is for the default font family, and `\sfdefault` for the default sans font. Package `helvet` redefines \sfdefault as `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}` (`phv` is the LaTeX name for Adobe Helvetica).

Comment: Okay, but `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}` does not modify font typeface as does `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} \usepackage{helvet}` though. I just tried it out. That is why to me there are certain commands that vary from compiler to compiler if I make sense. What are other alternatives to specify font, font size?

Comment: It does not vary for the same commands. The first command says tthe default font is the default sans font (usually it is `\rmdefault`, the roman default font). The second line says the default sans font for te document is Adobe Helvetica. To use another font with (pdf)LaTeX, you need a whole bunch of files (virtual fonts, .fd files, TeX metrics files, &c.) which are found in a package. For instance, such a package is `fourier`, which makes Adobe Utopia available, including for maths formulæ.

Comment: This question as it stands is really far too broad. Perhaps [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/11) and [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668) might be places to start. The documented source of the LaTeX kernel is to be found in the `source2e.pdf` which should be available via `texdoc source2e` or here: http://texdoc.net/pkg/source2e.

Comment: A full list?  If there are one:  `\def\ThisIsNotInTheList{I am not in the list}`.  The first to understand is that are the TeX primitives ( about 300) and there are macros using that primitives and macros using that macros,  and macros using macros based in another macros, and so son ...and anyone can make new macros. How to make a list of this?